# What is the second line of IDLE telling me about Python?

Tags: python, python-idle

The first line is obviously the language version. What is the second line in IDLE at startup? It looks like the ID of a C-compiler.

Here it is for version 2.7 (GCC):

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 26 2016, 12:10:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

... and version 3.7 (Clang):

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

More importantly what does it mean for the language? Is it the Python interpreter's compiler and does it mean something about speed and performance of this version of the language? I always think of this language in terms of being "interpreted" and not "compiled" so how does knowledge of the interpreter's compiler benefit me as a programmer?

Comment: Python scripts are interpreted by the python binary, which is compiled.

Comment: @Taegyung: Yeah, you're right. I misspoke - didn't pay attention to *darwin* in the message. Managed to correct it before the edit window expired. Thanks for pointing it out. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the dup link. That answers my question.

Comment: These two lines are one line wrapped because of how narrow your window is.  This line, `f"Python {sys.version} on {sys.platform}\n"`, is printed by *python* when you start the standard shell either from an icon or by entering `python` or `python3` in the terminal.  IDLE imitates the standard interpreter by printing the same line.